# TypeError using numpy.datetime64 in a structured array

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv, numpy, datetime

Running the script results in an exception: **TypeError int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'datetime.datetime'** at line
`data = np.asarray(tmp, dtype=data_type)`

```
from datetime import datetime
import numpy as np


data_type = [("Scan", "i4"), ("Time", "M8[us]"), ("101 (C)", "f8"), ("Alarm 
             101", "?"), ("102 (C)", "f8"), ("Alarm 102", "?")]
data_text = """1,12/6/2018 09:22:25:462,22.661,0,22.046,0
               2,12/6/2018 09:22:35:446,22.874,0,22.289,0
               3,12/6/2018 09:22:45:446,22.948,0,22.385,0"""


def main():
    tmp = []
    for line in data_text.split("\n"):
        dataLine = []
        for (h, _), v in zip(data_type, line.split(",")):
            if h == "Scan":
                dataLine.append(int(v))
            elif h == "Time":
                # dataLine.append(datetime.strptime(v, "%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S:%f"))
                dataLine.append(np.datetime64(datetime.strptime(v, "%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S:%f"), "us"))
            elif "Alarm" in h:
                dataLine.append(bool(v))
            else:
                dataLine.append(float(v))
        tmp.append(dataLine)
    data = np.asarray(tmp, dtype=data_type)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

From the numpy documentation, I see no reason it should not work. Best I can figure is that there something I am missing about numpy structured arrays. Is it a syntax issue, a numpy bug, or even possible to do with numpy?

My set up:

- Windows 10
- Python version 3.7.0
- Numpy version 1.15.4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to convert the `dataLine` list to a tuple and it will work just fine. That is because your `array` should preserve the shape (3,). Using `dataLine` as a list `asarray` will interpret each individual value as part of a multidimensional array with shape (3,6) and the dtype you want wouldn't be respected.

```
def main():
    tmp = []
    for line in data_text.split("\n"):
        dataLine = []
        for (h, _), v in zip(data_type, line.split(",")):
            if h == "Scan":
                dataLine.append(int(v))
            elif h == "Time":
                # dataLine.append(datetime.strptime(v, "%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S:%f"))
                dataLine.append(np.datetime64(datetime.strptime(v, "%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S:%f"), "us"))
            elif "Alarm" in h:
                dataLine.append(bool(v))
            else:
                dataLine.append(float(v))
        tmp.append(tuple(dataLine))

    data = np.asarray(tmp, dtype=data_type)
```

Comment: Now reviewing the numpy documentation, I see exactly what you are talking about. From the documentation: "Assignment from Python Native Types (Tuples)
The simplest way to assign values to a structured array is using python tuples. Each assigned value should be a tuple of length equal to the number of fields in the array, and not a list or array as these will trigger numpy’s broadcasting rules. The tuple’s elements are assigned to the successive fields of the array, from left to right." [Numpy Structured Array](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/user/basics.rec.html)